# How to merge different colors from different images into one?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

I have two sets of images: blue and red. I would like to take each image and merge them together, while adding T to red channel and D to the blue channel:

[Blue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPU0l.png) + [Red Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT6HU.png) = [Merged Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wBlG.png)

I use these lines of codes to do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

blue = cv2.imread("blue.png", 1)
red = cv2.imread("red.png", 1)

bb, bg, br = cv2.split(blue)
rb, rg, rr = cv2.split(red)
merged = cv2.merge((bb, rr))
```

Obviously, this is not going to work. Because i have to provide a value for green channel too. But, if i add the green channel either from red image or blue image, it will change the color of other objects in the merged image. I also tried to make some arbitrary numpy array as well, But it does not work either:

```
green = np.zeros((rr.shape))
merged = cv2.merge((bb, green, rr))
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `np.zeros` for the green channel. This will not effect the display.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


blue = cv2.imread("blue.png", 0)
red = cv2.imread("red.png", 0)

green = np.zeros_like(blue)

rgb = np.dstack((red,green,blue))


plt.imshow(rgb,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]